# Hide div and display other DIV on hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover

How can I have divs change on hover?

This is an example what i want to do: [JS FIDDLE](http://goo.gl/SJ7cL)

Comment: Could you clarify here? Do you need this done with pure CSS or is JS an option here? Let us know; your question's been re-tagged to attract knowledge on both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want JS?

```
<style>
    #container #divB{ display: none; }
    #container:hover #divB{ display: block; }
    #container:hover #divA{ display: none; }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="divA">
        DIV A is visible until hover
    </div>
    <div id="divB">
        DIV B must show up after hover DIV A and DIV A must hide
    </div>
</div>
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KtckK/

Comment: yes, im yet did that, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle, the example uses jQuery.

```
$('#divA').hover(

function () { // On mouse over
    $(this).hide(); // this references the div.
}

//function () { // On mouse out
//   $(this).show(); // this references the div.
//}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eJ6Rq/11/

Let me know if that's what you're looking for or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jQuery, see http://jsfiddle.net/eJ6Rq/3/

```
$('#divA').hover(function(){$(this).hide(); $('#divB').show();});
```